# Aggreagtion ytd revenue using Navicat

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

I am trying to find ytd revenue in one single row. Currently, I can pull the dataset by monthly using group by. But I want aggregation in one single row per year.

My current query -

select col_1, col_2, col_3, sum(col_4) as ytdrevenue

from table_1

group by 1,2,3
;

Sample out now -

01/01/2019 $2000

02/01/2019 $2000

Desired output - 
ytd $4000

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you grouping by, it’s very hard to help you when we have no idea what your table looks like.

Comment: Grouping by month, name. Month is in date format.

Comment: Why don’t you include the proper query and also some sample data and expected output

Comment: Updated in the original question.

Comment: Date is a string?

Comment: Nope - Its a date field.

Comment: Then the given answer should work

Comment: Nope. Its not working. I mentioned it in the comment.

Comment: I know, what I meant is that I don't have an answer because the given one looks like the right one to me.

Answer (score 0):

use `year()`
Assume you have a date column `col1` pick year from that column by using `year()` function

```
select year(col1),sum(col4) as yearwisetotal
from table group by year(col1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. It shows - No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is so hard to get information I am turning this around and post my answer as a question. Please explain what I have misunderstood with the below code.

Test table

```
create table test (
  col_1 date,
  col_2 varchar(20),
  col_3 int)
```

Some data

```
insert into test values ('2019-01-23', 'abc', 2000), ('2019-02-25', 'abc' ,2000)
```

Query

```
SELECT YEAR(col_1) as year, col_2, SUM(col_3) ytdrevenue
FROM test
GROUP BY year, col_2
```

Result

```
year    col_2   ytdrevenue
2019    abc           4000
```